# change configuration of webpart with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have a webpart applied on a sample page: `http://mysite/page/registration`

I need to change the `TYPE` property of the webpart on this page.

Answer (score 1):

i found 1 way

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://server/")
$web = $site.OpenWeb("/")
$resultsPath = "Paginas/default.aspx"
$page = $web.GetFile($resultsPath)
$page.CheckOut()
$wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($resultsPath, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$wpm.WebParts | ft Title, StorageKey 
$refinerManager = $wpm.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "WP_IntegracaoLumis"}
Write-Host $refinerManager
$refinerManager.Tipo= "DEFAULT 2"
$wpm.SaveChanges($refinerManager)  #ERROR
write-Host 
Write-Host "WebPart em $resultsPath Alterada"

$page.CheckIn("Test")
$page.Publish("Test")
$web.Close()
$site.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Following are the steps with powershell commands to update the webpart property](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-setupdate-webpart-property-using.html)

1. Get the site
2. Since we have to throughout the site collection, among all the web
   we will go through all the webs
3. Now, we need to read welcome page of every web
4. Once we got the welcome page, get the file and checkout it
5. Now from welcome page we will get webpart manager
6. Now we have webpartmanager from the page, we can traverse through
   all webparts and check for the webpart for which we need to
   set/update the property
7. Check in and Publish the file - #more details – SPFile.CheckIn()
8. Finally dispose the site object

Below the complete powershell script

```
$site = Get-SPSite "SiteCollectionURL"
$webcoll = $site.AllWebs
 #Step through each web in site collection
foreach ($web in $webcoll) {
#Get the root folder
$folder = $web.RootFolder
#Get the welcome page
$welcomepage = $folder.WelcomePage
$file = $web.GetFile("$welcomepage")
$file.CheckOut()
$wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("$welcomepage", [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
foreach($webpart in $wpm.WebParts){
            if($webpart.MyUniqueProperty){
if(!$webpart. MyUniqueProperty){
$webpart. MyUniqueProperty = $ MyUniquePropertyValue(Value which need to be Set/Update)
                                    $wpm.SaveChanges($webpart)
}#First If
}#Second If
}#Foreach
$file.CheckIn("Updated/Set property of webpart",1)
            $file.Publish("Updated/Set property of webpart")
            $site.Dispose()           
}#foreach
```